# Why doesn't Professor Xavier use Wolverine's healing power to fix his legs?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Why hasn't Professor X used Wolverine's DNA to heal his spine, or whatever injury caused him to be unable to use his legs. If Stryker can put DNA (with powers) into anyone, why doesn't Professor X, who is a much more intelligent person with an unlimited budget, do the experiment? He is friends with Wolverine, after all.

Comment: Does Xavier WANT his legs back?

Comment: I suppose so. Who doesnt need his legs. and can we say, What if .. What if he likes his legs back.

Comment: Xavier and the X-Men typically shy away from genetic experiments on mutants. Historically, such things end badly.

Comment: He probably likes the nickname "Wheels" better than "Chrome Dome"

Comment: I haven't followed comics for years, but as I recall, back in the early New Mutants run, Xavier was grumbling because he was physically fine, but there was some kind of block in his mind keeping him from using his legs, which, for a telepath, is just depressing.  Later, he did use them.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @KeithHWeston.

Comment: @Phantom42 - You could probably make that into an answer.

Comment: Thereafter, he could use Wolverine's healing power to grow back his lush, thick head of hair.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't followed the X-men or New Mutants (or any related groups) for quite a few years, but I remember that near the beginning of the New Mutants, Professor X was irritated at his inability to walk, as his body was fine; it was nothing more than psychosomatic pain that kept him from walking.  As possibly the most powerful telepath on earth, that was rather frustrating and confusing to him.

[image]

He was later able to walk; how long it lasted is unknown to me, as I stopped reading around then.

Comment: nice answer. so it isnt something that nicked his spine. it was more of a psycho... something problem

Comment: No, his original injury was from Lucifer dropping a rock on his legs. The psychosomatic pain was a complication later after Lilandra tried to cure him.

[Here](http://i939.photobucket.com/albums/ad236/beecover/fourkeys.jpg) is where the slab is dropped on him.

Comment: ill look at the link when i get home. So the First Class is a remake?

Comment: @Sid: Yes, to some extent.  There have been several alternate versions of this one implied by various comics and movies, besides the original version above.  (I vastly prefer the Ultimate universe version, in which Magneto did it.  Much better for both characters.)

Answer (score 7):

Xavier and the X-Men typically shy away from genetic experiments on Mutants. Historically, such experiments end badly or are so morally questionable that it's a line they just don't want to cross.

He has, however, had his legs cured by the results (or more specifically the side effects) of genetic experimentation (the Legacy Virus) and by the powers of another mutant (Xorn).